# Django REST Swagger hiding ModelViewSet with permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I used [Django REST Swagger](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in my Django project. It is able to show all the URL with views which does not have 
 `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`. While the view with  `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]` is not shown in the list-api.

Here is an example:

```
class EquipmentCategoryViewSet(ResponseMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EquipmentCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EquipmentCategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

if i remove  `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`, it is shown in the swagger list-api. 
I downgraded swagger to 2.1.2 and clicked on authorized and passed the token.

The strange thing is I have a prefix '**Token**' in my value. When i login with  `Token<tokenvalue>`  login fails. But when I pass `<tokenvalue>` it gets authenticated but the views with *isAuthenticated*  is not shown.

Please suggest what should be done to show views with *isAuthenticated* added.

Answer (score 1):

In document API top right corner there is a option for authorise or to log in. Do provide valid token in it or login. This will list other endpoints.

Use swagger 2.1.2.

> The latest django swagger version 2.2 has some issue with
>   authorization. Refer:
>   https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/762

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I used Django rest_auth, which uses token authentication. How do i deal with that?

Comment: Which swagger version is you using?

Comment: Version : 2.2.0

Comment: Downgrade it to 2.1.2. Or it may cause some issue.

Comment: Downgraded to 2.1.2. User is authorized but all URL is not shown.

Comment: Did you authorize?

Comment: In your page press authorize and give valid token id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181614/discussion-between-shrestha-rohit-and-a-k-v).

Answer (score 1):

you can just override the schema

```
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

from rest_framework_swagger import renderers


schema_view = get_schema_view(title="Fbs Api Docs", public=True, renderer_classes=[renderers.OpenAPIRenderer, renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer])
```

you pass the public=True it will allow all api to list, in 
urls.py include below

```
path('docs/', schema_view),
```